# Area of Peano Curve

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Since peano curves, as space filling curves, occupy all the area of space, let us say, $[0,1]\times[0,1]$, do they have area 1 square unit?

They should have. However, Whether I take limit, or anything, how can I possible get the area component, all I get is length only (i dont exactly get the length but **I hope you get it**)?

If it's area is indeed 1 square unit, is it possible to derive without based on the assumption, that it fills the space, that it's area is indeed 1 square unit?

Something like,

Comment: I think to remember that the Hausdorff measure of the Peano curve is indeed 2, but this is not "area" in the sense you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it’s a question of definitions more than anything else. A *parametrized curve* in the unit square $S$ we may define to be a continuous function $f\colon[0,1]\to S$. Under this definition, what can we mean by the “area” of the curve? I think the only way to define this is to say that it’s the Lebesgue measure of the image (sometimes called the range) of $f$, that is, the set $f\bigl([0,1]\bigr)$. If $f$ is a space-filling curve like the Peano curve, then, the area is $1$.

There certainly are other definitions of “curve”. For instance, you might say that a curve in $S$ is a subset that is locally the union of finitely many analytic curves. Such a set would be nowhere dense, so its area would be zero. If you accept this definition, you see that the Peano “curve” is not a curve.